# Print outer HTML Containing table

Tags: excel, vba

I am Trying this but its bringing wrong data pls help.

```
Public Sub Test_H1()
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet, url As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
Dim i, j As Integer

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=2132&symbol=DIVISLAB"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With
Set html = New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = sResponse

clipboard.SetText html.querySelector("table").outerHTML
clipboard.PutInClipboard
ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

The link is "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=2132&symbol=DIVISLAB"

[The table which is containing data is in red box in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsCMq.png)

The table id is also in it "octable" , if any one could help it will be grateful.

Comment: Content is dynamically retrieved from alternate endpoint